# How to count occurences of a specific word in MS Word document

Tags: c#, find

I want to search how many times a specific word exists in a MS word file. I tried a loop on docs.Words, but it takes so much time... In the search options there in an option "Find in -> Main document", and in few seconds it tells u the number. How can I do this in C#? Where is it in Selection.Find?

Answer (score 0):

lets assume `someWord` is the word you would like to found and `Words.doc` is the name of the document. Try like:

```
var myText = File.ReadAllLines(myPAth+"Words.doc");
var wordsInText = myText.Split(" ");
var numberOfOccurences = wordsInText.Count(x=>x=="someWord");
```

Comment: Additional info, if you also need to check for occurrences of your word in the header and footer area, then you might need some different code for that if i remember correctly.

Comment: You don't need to split the text first: var numberOfOccurrences = Regex.Matches(wordsInText, @"\bsomeWord\b").Count;

Comment: Im sorry but ReadAllLines doesn't work well with .docx files... It returns kindof binary data. Maybe with .doc, But I get many docx files and I need to check in each how many specific words they contain.